# How to send js variables to values of contact form 7?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

all!
There is a form (not a contact form 7) with two inputs. When someone fills out this form and clicks on submit button I need the new form (CF7) to pop-up 
with inputs already filled in with the values from the previous form and with more new inputs to fill out.
So, how can I send the variables from the first form to the second one? Any ideas?
Or maybe there is another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the submit event.

Prevent default.

Get the data in the form elements.

Fill the data to DOM.

--or--

Just make a fake button writes submit on it.

Catch click event and do the same.

Create the new form with the new data.

Comment: "Create the new form with the new data." This form (new one) is created by contact form 7 plugin by using wordpress shortcode and I can't send data through shortcode.

Comment: Ah i am sorry i didn't have read properly then. I thought it was plain html forms. Good luck then.